# Timestamp java spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, timestamp

Como faço para salvar uma data no banco de dados automaticamente usando timestamp?
(salvar automaticamente a data do insert no banco de dados)

Comment: Provavelmente nem precisa de Java para isso, provavelmente no seu banco você pode definir o valor padrão da coluna como algo equivalente à `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Consegui fazer salvar o seguinte:
"timestamp_cadastro":"2023-03-13T21:28:43.997+00:00"
porem tenho que salvar neste formato:
"timestamp_cadastro": 1636636150

usei o seguinte para conseguir salvar setando um valor padrao como sugeriu:
 @Column(name="timestamp_cadastro", columnDefinition="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
 private Timestamp timestamp_cadastro;

teria alguma dica de como faço para deixar no padrao que preciso ?